# Custom block not showing up in block editor

Tags: wordpress, plugins, editor, block

I'm having an issue with a custom block that I created for WordPress. The block is supposed to show up in the "Custom Blocks" category in the block editor, but it's not appearing when I search for it.

I've checked the PHP and JavaScript code for the plugin and everything seems to be correct. I've also tried adding some debugging code to see if the functions are being called correctly, but I'm still not able to figure out what's causing the issue.

Here is the PHP code for the plugin:

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Related Post Block
Description: Adds a custom block to generate related post code snippets.
*/

// Enqueue the block editor assets
add_action('enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'related_post_block_enqueue_assets');

function related_post_block_enqueue_assets() {
    // Enqueue the JavaScript file for the block
    wp_enqueue_script(
        'related-post-block',
        plugins_url('block.js', __FILE__),
        array('wp-blocks', 'wp-editor', 'wp-components', 'wp-api-fetch', 'wp-element'), // Add wp-element as a dependency
        filemtime(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'block.js')
    );
}

// Register the block category
add_filter('block_categories', 'related_post_block_add_category');

function related_post_block_add_category($categories) {
    return array_merge(
        $categories,
        array(
            array(
                'slug'  => 'custom-blocks',
                'title' => 'Custom Blocks',
                'icon'  => 'admin-generic'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

And here is the JavaScript code for the block:

```
(function (blocks, editor, components, apiFetch) {
    var el = blocks.element.createElement;
    var __ = wp.i18n.__;

    blocks.registerBlockType('custom-blocks/related-post', {
        title: __('Related Post', 'related-post-block'),
        icon: 'admin-links',
        category: 'custom-blocks',
        keywords: [__('related'), __('post')],
        attributes: {
            url: {
                type: 'string',
                source: 'attribute',
                attribute: 'data-url',
                selector: 'input[type="url"]'
            }
        },
        edit: function (props) {
            var attributes = props.attributes;

            function updateUrl(event) {
                props.setAttributes({ url: event.target.value });
            }

            return el(
                'div',
                {},
                el(
                    'input',
                    {
                        type: 'url',
                        placeholder: __('Paste the post URL', 'related-post-block'),
                        value: attributes.url,
                        onChange: updateUrl
                    }
                ),
                el(
                    editor.InspectorControls,
                    {},
                    el(
                        components.PanelBody,
                        { title: __('Options', 'related-post-block'), initialOpen: true },
                        el(
                            components.PanelRow,
                            {},
                            el(
                                components.Button,
                                {
                                    isPrimary: true,
                                    onClick: function () {
                                        var generateUrl = '/wp-json/related-post-block/v1/generate';
                                        apiFetch({ path: generateUrl, method: 'POST', body: attributes.url })
                                            .then(function (response) {
                                                if (response && response.data) {
                                                    editor.DomUtils.insertHTML(
                                                        document.activeElement,
                                                        response.data
                                                    );
                                                }
                                            });
                                    }
                                },
                                __('Generate', 'related-post-block')
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            );
        },
        save: function () {
            return null; // Save is handled on the server-side
        }
    });
})(window.wp.blocks, window.wp.editor, window.wp.components, window.wp.apiFetch);
```

I would really appreciate any help or suggestions on how to resolve this issue. Thank you in advance!

I want to add a custom block in the WordPress post editor. When you type "/related" in the editor, a box should appear where you can paste a URL, and it will automatically generate the related post code snippet based on that URL.